Order of CSS Grid is off
Codepen: https://codepen.io/saerts/pen/poBxzNR
I have an HTML setup like this:
<div class="container">
  <div class="block top">Top</div>
  <div class="block main">Main 1/3</div>
  <div class="block main">Main 2/3</div>
  <div class="block bottom">Bottom</div>
</div>

My CSS is :
.container{
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr min-content;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); 
  grid-gap: 8px;
}
.top{
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
.bottom{
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
.main{
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
      
  &:nth-child(2){
    grid-column: 2 / 4;
  }
}
.block{
  padding: 8px;;
  background: lightgrey;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

Why does the 2nd div.main (1/3) shows up in another order than expected?


You have TWO divs with the class of main so the browser tries to put them in the same place.

But why, I put different css on them (nt-child) ?

That's not how you select no.2 of a class. That selector just selects the 2nd child of the parent.

https://css-tricks.com/css-nth-of-class-selector/

The second .main div (2/3) appears in another order than expected because of the CSS selector &:nth-child(2).
In CSS, the :nth-child() pseudo-class selects elements based on their position among a group of siblings. In this case, .main:nth-child(2) selects the second .main element among its siblings. However, it's important to note that :nth-child() counts all children of the parent element, not just elements with the same class.
you can change the CSS to target the second .main specifically, rather than using :nth-child(2). You can do this by using a class or another selector that uniquely identifies the second .main element. Here's an example using a class:


.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr min-content;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 8px;
}

.top {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.bottom {
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.main {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.main.full-width {
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
}

.block {
  padding: 8px;
  background: lightgrey;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="block top">Top</div>
  <div class="block main">Main 1/3</div>
  <div class="block main full-width">Main 2/3</div>
  <div class="block bottom">Bottom</div>
</div>




Thx, I think that's the correct answer... It makes sense
